# About modifications of right-continuous stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Lemma : Let $X$ and $X'$ be two right continuous(or left continuous) processes defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ be a modification then the two processes are indistinguishable.
>
> Proof: Consider $$A=\{\omega|X_t(\omega)=X'_{t}(\omega) ,\forall t \in \mathbb{}Q^+\}.$$
> Since $X$ and $X'$ are modifications, we have that $\forall t$  $X_t(\omega)=X'_{t}(\omega) $ P a.s
> As $A^C$ is a countable union of sets of probability measure zero ( follows from the assumption that the two process are a modification), we have that $P(A^C)=0$, hence $P(A)=1$. $\Box$

I do not understand why right continuity implies that if we sum all $\omega$ over the reals , the new set A would have a probability 1 too. How do I rigorously prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking why two right-continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(q)=g(q)$ for every $q$ in $\mathbb Q$, coincide. Well, note that, for every $x$ not in $\mathbb Q$, $f(x)-g(x)$ is the limit of $f(q)-g(q)$ when $q\to x$, $q\gt x$, $q$ in $\mathbb Q$, hence $f(x)-g(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you Did. Though I thought I  knew why but i was looking for a more formal proof.I could not write it down .

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $X,Y$ are right-continuous, then
    \begin{align}
  \left\{ X_t = Y_t,\ \forall t \geq 0 \right\}
  = \bigcap_{r \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,\infty)} \left\{ X_r = Y_r \right\}
 \end{align}
     but $P(X_r = Y_r) = 1\   (\forall r \geq 0)$, then 
    \begin{align}
  P(X_t = Y_t,\ \forall t \geq 0)
  = P \biggl( \bigcap_{r \in \mathbb  Q \cap [0,\infty)} \left\{ X_r = Y_r \right\} \biggr)
  = 1.
 \end{align}